# XCopy folder with spaces in FinalBuilder

Tags: xcopy, finalbuilder

I'm trying to XCopy folder in FinalBuilder 8. However, the path to source folder contains spaces in it and looks like this

> \%Server%\inetpub\wwwroot\Payment System\%CurrentProjectAlias%\

And when I try to run XCopy action I got error code 4.
Is the any way to resolve this problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: `"quote paths with spaces like this"`

Answer (score 0):

As Alex K says, you will need to surround the path with double quotes.

```
"\\%Server%\inetpub\wwwroot\Payment System\%CurrentProjectAlias%\"
```